# How to delete failed Kubernetes pods automatically?

Tags: kubernetes

Pods in `error` state are not getting cleaned up.

I can manually remove these pods using:

```
kubectl delete pod --field-selector status.phase=Failed
```

Is there any `annotation` or `label` that I can use for auto-cleanup? What's the recommended way to do this?

Comment: The Pod [garbage collector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-garbage-collection) (PodGC), which is a controller in the control plane, cleans up terminated Pods (with a phase of **Succeeded** or **Failed**), when the number of Pods exceeds the configured threshold (determined by **terminated-pod-gc-threshold** in the kube-controller-manager). This avoids a resource leak as Pods are created and terminated over time.

Comment: Refer to a similar Github issue on [Auto-delete failed Pods \#99986](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/99986) for more details.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy you can add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [KEP-2307: Job tracking without lingering Pods](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-apps/2307-job-tracking-without-lingering-pods#deleted-pods) is now GA, since Kubernetes 1.25 (Aug. 2022)

It includes the ability, for a Job Controller, to [delete pods](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-apps/2307-job-tracking-without-lingering-pods#deleted-pods)

> In the case where a user or another controller removes a Pod, which sets a deletion timestamp, the Job controller treats it the same as any other Pod.
>
> Since deleted Pods with finalizers get inevitably marked as Failed, the Job controller already counts them as such and removes their finalizers.
>
> This is different from the legacy tracking, where the Job controller does not account for deleted Pods. This is a limitation that this KEP also wants to solve.

The counter ([JobTrackingWithFinalizers](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/113510/commits/4948918155012b24e4b1cf987f831639c6dbaf9c#diff-ce7b64e72add3d44567b11ab1a4b1e6bfc9345a86b4a352283140e4974776c4d)) is now available.

So a JobController with K8s 1.25+ should delete the pods, provided, the job itself has a TTL (Time-To-Live, K8s 1.23+) after cleanup, for "[Automatic Cleanup for Finished Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/ttlafterfinished/)".

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "echo 'Hello, World!'"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 3):

As per Kubernetes official doc on [Garbage collection of Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-garbage-collection);

> The Pod garbage collector (PodGC), which is a controller in the
> control plane, cleans up terminated Pods (with a phase of `Succeeded` or
> `Failed`), when the number of Pods exceeds the configured threshold
> (determined by `terminated-pod-gc-threshold` in the
> `kube-controller-manager`). This avoids a resource leak as Pods are
> created and terminated over time.

Refer to a similar Github issue on [Auto-delete failed Pods #99986](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/99986) for more details.

**Without Cronjob:** To clean up the failed pods created by kubernetes job automatically without using cronjob, you can set a [TTL](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#ttl-mechanism-for-finished-jobs) on your **Job** to have the pods cleaned up automatically.

**With Cronjob:**  *CleanUp Script* written by **Chris Ed Rego’s Medium blog** on [How to automatically clean up failed Kubernetes Pod every 24 hours](https://chrisedrego.medium.com/how-to-automatically-clean-up-failed-kubernetes-pod-every-24-hours-d66ac2a3964d), which may help to resolve your issue.

**Conclusion :** This may need a fundamental change in kubernetes. Seems you may need a github issue to discuss further on this issue.